# I have a problem installing ubuntu

Tags: boot, partitioning

I have been trying to install the latest version of ubuntu from a flash drive that i setted up with rufus. When the process begins i’m not able to succesfully pass through the point where it ask if you want to delete Windows because it sends a pop up that says “the attempt to mount a file system with type vfat in SCI1 (0,0,0) partition #1 (sda) at /boot/efi failed” and i cannot continue further. I have not tried anything since i don’t want to mess ir up.  What can i do to finalize the process?

Comment: If you intend to run a dual-boot then disabling Windows' Fast Startup feature is a must, even before installing. The error suggests that all partitions are in a dirty state, including the ESP.

Comment: Please try and be specific, but "*latest version of Ubuntu*" I take it you mean Ubuntu 22.10 or the October-2022 release, but you didn't say if you're asking about Server, Desktop or something else, ie. you've not told us which installer you're using which gives us clues as to what you're likely seeing.  What ISO of the *latest* Ubuntu 22.10 are you using?